# Sending email on a local area network, between PCs (or Just one pc acting as sender and receiver)

Tags: networking, email, microsoft-outlook, lan, gmail

Ok here's the deal, im doing a short-film, 
it has a shot where the character1 orders a book online (amazon etc I can fake ordering part), but there's another scene where  character2 reads the delivery update mail from amazon.com,

it would look like this- character2 notices notification (windows 10 mail client) (of delivery update email from amzon) on char1 laptop->proceeds to click on it,reads it googles it, finds out ulterior motives etc etc.

```
Basically I just need this--

Recieve a mail with sender appearing to be amazon.com , so that character1 
email/laptop shows (windows 10) mail notification, on which char2 can click
```

I tried many fake email services, php fake email scripts, ran a script with QK smtp server [but recieving providers all blocked it (live.com/gmail.com /spamhaus)]
I tried setting up localmailserver with "AA mail" (seems we can set up any domain name with it) but cant seem to get it right.

I created the domain name and account name and all in AAmail, I tried sending email between accounts from within AAmail,(status pane at bottom of AAmail shows email sent and received by respective accounts, can send but cant view the mail from AAmail window)

but I cant find out how to make these accounts work with windows 10 mail client,
cant send/receive email when I add these accounts to Windows 10mail client (my idea was to create two accounts, 1 as orderupdate@amazon.com and the 2nd the receiving account johnxyz@gmail.com, but i dont think I succeeded in setting up this right in windows 10 mail client

[AAmail main window showing account and mail recieved status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fdS1.png)

[QK smtp phpscript fake mail-failure log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge0ZI.png)

Comment: It sounds to me like you're trying to create an imitation order confirmation email from Amazon.com for a film, and want the 'From:` field to read "Amazon.com." However, the issue you're running into is that your mail client keeps flagging your fake email as a phishing attack and deleting the email. Is this more or less correct?

Comment: Seems like a lot of work. Being 90%+ of people literally don’t have a clue or will not even look at that level of detail, it seems silly to go through this much trouble. Give the sense of an email coming in then simply show only a clipped screenshot of some mail content. There are literally so many different, better ways to accomplish this task for the purpose of a film. Stop being a technician for a moment and be a director.

Comment: @Cancun101 Exactly, I'm just trying to imitate receiving the email from Amazon, I dont think my fake mails even reach my mail client, they get flagged down way before that, (see attached QK Smtp mail failure log) at the internet post office of sorts?

Comment: @Appleoddity  Yes I've faked the content of the email, but I cant seem to create a fake impression of receiving the mail, the thing is Char2 doesnt just go straight up snooping into char1's business, char1 is kind of missing/has been showing lots of suspicious activity lately, char2 only notices the email because the email notification lights up the inactive screen of char2's unattended laptop, he goes to power it down,notices email of delivey completed --gets interest piqued

Comment: @all So thats why I went the LAN mail server route, thinking it had better chance of working and producing desired result if set up properly, [AAmail LAN server](http://www.aamailsoft.com/create-lan-mail-server.htm) I'm open to other suggestions as well, frankly im out of ideas , pulled my hair out tring to get this work, (have faked email content, and fake google search results parts)

Also worth mentioning I'm the "tech support dude" (knows how to google stuff better), and this is the my friend's (the "director")very first attempt at making a short-film.. so you know... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: If you've figured it out yourself, go ahead and write up what you found to work as an answer. That way others will be able to find your answer in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to Cancun101 I've somewhat figured it out, just click on the mail settings (gear shaped icon just above the inbox  mail list) and > "Accounts and import" tab> then change the "send mail as" ("edit info")part from the sending account and you can change it to whatever name and as many times as you'd like.( this will change the author name in the inbox mail list, but on viewing that individual  mail it will still show the original mail address)
[mail settings icon location (I had trouble finding it thefirst time, hence the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYRjy.png)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might try is simply sending an email with the content of an Amazon receipt from any personal email, and then going to the receiving gmail account and renaming the contact as "Amazon.com" or the like. That way the actual sender's email will be hidden.

It will likely be flagged as spam or phishing and put in your junk mail folder, but you can simply move it out and mark it as unread to make it seem like it's just been received.

Let me know if this works!

Comment: Renaming the contact from receiving account did not work for me, but thanks to you while googling why it did not work, I found that you can edit the "send as" part from the sending email account, IT WORKED !!!!!   thanks a lot, cant believe I spent such a lot of time for such a simple thing, anyways, guess I learned how easy it is to fake emails. :D